# android "Could not find method"

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to run some code on Android that uses an external library JSoup. I add the required jar to my build path and Eclipse shows that there are no errors. When I attempt to run the program on Android I get this error in LogCat.

"Could not find method org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect, referenced from method test.android.MyTestAndroidActivity.test"

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eY_uqi_qIz0

Answer (score 1):

If you have this problem after upgrading to SDK 17 (or possibly later), please check bug reported here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27490